# SIFR, JAVASCRIPT & PHP - How to apply SIFR to dynamically loaded content

Tags: sifr, sifr3

Well here's the problem:

I have a PHP index page which uses show/hide layers javascript. I am using the on menu.click function to show and hide content relevant to each menu. On.click all divs are hidden except the content for that menu item , which fades in. The content relating to each menu item are displayed within separate DIVS. The  property is applied to all the text within all the divs.

See: http://jobe-group.com/jobeco/uk/2010live/dynamic/content/index.php#

The trouble is that SIFR only appears to be applied to the  displayed on.load when the page is first loaded. When this  is hidden and the other s shown through the "show" function they load in classic CSS fonts without the SIFR applied.

Is this unavoidable with the SIFR setup. Or am I not calling the divs properly. I have set the SIFR to apply to the  selector and indeed it works fine on the  for the  displayed on load. It doesn't work for the  within other . In theory I would think its possible to load the SIFR on all divs on page.load even if those divs are presently visibility:hidden.

What's the verdict on this?

Hope someone can help.

Cheers,
John

Answer (score 0):

After you show the previously hidden `div`, execute the `sIFR.replace` calls again to replace the content in those elements.